# Express these polynomials in terms of orthogonal ones

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

In a problem in QM I faced with this polynomials, sadly they are not orthogonal. I was wondering if someone else knows these polynomials, I was looking up and didn't find anything about them but they are similar to Hermite's Polynomials

The polynomials of order $2p+1$ are given by,

$$
P(x)=x \prod_{i=1}^{P}(-4i+x^2)
$$

This polynomial was the result of finding the eigenvalues of a combination of some matrices.

My question is: Is there a way to express this polynomial as some other orthogonal polynomials?

I need an orthogonal form of $P(x)$ in order to find orthogonal eigenvectors of my matrices.

Comment: Hi! I think you should specify more: what do you exactly want to know about the polynomials, apart from "Has someone met them before"? I see that the polynomials are of the form $\cdots(x−2\sqrt3)(x−2\sqrt2)(x−2)x(x+2)(x+2\sqrt2)(x+2\sqrt3)\cdots$ and this info is enough for most applications that come to mind!

Comment: Orthogonal over what domain ? Under what weight ?

Comment: When you edit your question in response to some commentary, it is best that you make another commentary yourself with a warning, and putting @name on it, so that the person who did the useful commentary gets a notice. Otherwise, we have to remember that you had this question pending, and come to see if you have updated it!

Comment: @SamuelWalton What do you mean by "express" and "orthogonal form"? A linear combination of orthogonal polynomials?